# How to designate specific versions of e.g. Ubuntu containers?

Tags: docker, package-managers

I just had my dockerized app not able to build for a day because apparently the "ubuntu:14.04" image still gets revved over time, and a newer OS level package version sabotaged me (this was unexpected - I'm careful to only apt-get install, pip install, etc. hardcoded versions of package so that I know when they change).  Is there a way to control how/when I'm getting "newer 14.04's"?  Not a desktop hack, I need it to work on the build server too when I submit my app to build.

Comment: See https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/

you can find 14.04, or 14.04.4 (which the now the latest)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu publish dated [tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/ubuntu/tags/) to the registry.

```
$ docker run ubuntu:trusty-20160526  cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
```

Comment: How reliable are these?  I note with sadness that there's a lot more trusty-<datestamps> than there are 14.04.x tags, which tells me they update the 14.04.x tags across several real builds? Are even the trusty-<datestamp> ones guaranteed to be stable?

Comment: I can't say for sure as I'm not involved in the process but it looks like they increment a build number `.1`, `.2` etc for multiple builds on the one day.